# how to create a record on custom object when a new feed is created

Tags: apex, chatter

I have one requirement from client side,in that when we create a feed item, a new record in a custom object should be created having the feed item along with the feed created user name

Comment: people can help you if you provide what you have tried and explain where you are facing the difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a Trigger on FeedItem After Insert and write your logic to create the record in the Custom Object!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ID, CreatedDate, CreatedById, CreatedBy.FirstName, CreatedBy.LastName, ParentId, Parent.Name, Body FROM FeedItem

This will give you all information about the feed and the one who posted and use them to insert in the custom object using trigger.